# Dragging an image and leaving it where it was dragged on the iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have a map image and I would like to be able to drag the image somewhere on the screen and then be able to go get another image from a webserver with the new map image being where the old image was dragged.

I've tried the UIImageView in a UIScrollView but the image is bounced back to fill the screen if I try to drag it off. Setting the UIScrollView .bounces = NO isn't what I need either because that just prevents me from dragging the image off of the screen. Is there an easy way to get this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using UIPinchGestureRecognizer and UIPanGestureRecognizer to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at the `UIResponder` methods `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded`.